# Inverse Laplace transform of Dirac delta function

Tags: functional-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-problems

I am trying to understand how to identify, or at least derive some properties of the inverse Laplace transform of the Dirac delta function, i.e. a function $\eta$ s.t.
$$
   \int_0^\infty dt\, \eta(\omega,t) e^{-\omega’ t} = \delta(\omega-\omega’) \,.
$$

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such function $\eta$...

Comment: Are $\omega$ and $\omega'$ meant to be complex variables ?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker the numerically feasible solution proposed e.g. here [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~cle/papers/laplce_rev2.pdf] provides one alternative way to identify the above "function". Instead, I still cannot understand its analytic properties, e.g. I believe that the wildly oscillating nature of coefficients arises right from the behavior of the above "function", yet I cannot have a grasp on it

Comment: @Abezhiko They are meant to be real variables, since the original problem involves the inversion of the Laplace transform on the real axis only

Comment: @CarloBeenakker. How about a distribution?

Comment: @md2perpe this is precisely what I have in mind! The answer below by Abezhiko might be a first attempt, though not fully resolutive

Answer (score 1):

The answer might not be definitive and depends on the context. Even if you intend to carry real computations ultimately, the Laplace transform is assumed to be defined with respect to a complex variable or, at the very least, it may be analytically continued to the complex plane for convergence purposes. In the present case, it allows us to "cheat" a little bit, because the Dirac delta function is simply represented by the inverse function in the complex plane thanks to Cauchy's formula. Concretely, one has $\delta(z) \equiv \frac{1}{2\pi iz}$, whose inverse transform is easily found as the Heaviside function. In consequence, one can conclude that $\eta(\omega,t) = \frac{e^{\omega t}}{2\pi i}u(t)$.

Alternatively and a bit more naively, you could also apply Mellin's inverse formula directly, i.e.
$$
\eta(\omega,t) = \mathscr{L}^{-1}[\delta(\omega'-\omega)](t) = \int_{\omega-i\Bbb{R}}^{\omega+i\Bbb{R}} \frac{\mathrm{d}\omega'}{2\pi i}\, \delta(\omega'-\omega)e^{\omega't} = \frac{e^{\omega t}}{2\pi i}.
$$

Comment: Now, if we plug your solution into the original equation, we end up with (for $\omega > \omega'$ only?)
$$
\int_0^\infty dt \, \frac{e^{\omega t}}{2\pi i} e^{-\omega' t} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{\omega' - \omega}
$$
which I believe we can treat with the standard $\varepsilon$-prescription
$$
\frac{1}{x+i\varepsilon} = \mathrm{PV}\left(\frac1x\right) - i\pi\delta(x)
$$
to obtain
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{\omega-\omega'} = -\frac12 \delta(\omega-\omega') + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \mathrm{PV}\left(\frac1{\omega-\omega'}\right) \,.
$$

Comment: Would you now conclude by saying that (up to normalization factors which can be easily reabsorbed in the definition of $\eta(\omega,t)$ only the real contribution counts, since the original integral is purely real? If so, why is this equivalence valid also distributionally?